# Classical guitar techique to play artificial harmonics while striking three bass strings

Tags: guitar, technique, classical-guitar

Is there a technique that would allow me to play something like this? I have my pinky and ring finger free, but i don't know if i could possibly play it with them. I'm just stuck at this point. Striking all the strings with my thumb doesn't produce the right sound. I have to somehow pick them.

[image]

Comment: I must ask, are you certain the tab is correct? If you know the name of the piece, we might find that the tab is inaccurate. If it is correct,you could research how other performers handled this. In fact, you might even be able to do that without our help if your ear is good enough!

Comment: Why can't you use your pinky or ring finger to play the harmonic? I assume you are talking about your plucking hand here. It seems perfectly doable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I used my ring finger. I do not strike all the strings with my thumb though. Particularly because artificial harmonics produce less volume and you don't wanna "make" more sound by striking the muted strings.

For the first cord I pluck the E string with my thumb and the other three with my I M and ring finger of my left hand. The two other cords I pluck the three base notes with the thumb and the e string with my ring finger of my left hand.

The left hand movement is kind of like when you want to pluck only both E string. As examples: Black bird from the Beatles or fast car from Tracy. Only in this case you let the thumb "slide" through the strings and pluck the three base strings.

Make sure to master the left hand movement before trying the artificial harmonics, just play the 8th fret at first. once you feel comfortable, then you
ll just have to lift the finger a bit for the artificial harmonics.

Comment: I think you're describing a Natural Harmonic. For this to be an Artificial Harmonic, you should fret the string at the 8th fret and touch the string with the right hand (presumably at the 20th fret).